# NSView - Drawing 2-Color Checkers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have a subclass of NSView where I need to draw two-color checkers (squares of alternating colors).  The following is what I have.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {    
    NSInteger k = 1;
    for (int j = 0;  j < self.frame.size.width; j += 20) {
        for (int i = 0; i < self.frame.size.height; i +=20) {
            if (k%2 == 0) {
                [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
            }
            else {
                [[NSColor lightGrayColor] set];
            }
            [NSBezierPath fillRect:NSMakeRect(j,i,20,20)];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run it, I get squares of alternating colors.  If I change the frame height, I sometimes get stripes of alternating colors.  How can I improve the code above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of determining square color alternates the color down a column and then continues with the next column. If you have an even number of rows each row will start with the same color, giving you stripes.

Think simple, you only need two states - black or white - so instead of integers, addition, and odd/even tests to reduce an integer to one of two values just start with a type with only two values, that is Boolean.

To deal with the issue of an odd or even number of rows use two variables, one to track the color of the first square in the column - this will flip each iteration of your outer loop, and one to track the color of the current square - for each column this starts with the value of the first variable and flips each iteration of the inner loop.

In code outline, before the outer loop:

```
BOOL colStartsWhite = YES; // or NO, you decide - this is the corner color
```

Inside the outer loop:

```
BOOL squareIsWhite = colStartsWhite; // inner tracker
colStartsWhite = !colStartsWhite; // flip ready for next column
```

Inside the inner loop:

```
if (squareIsWhite) ... else ... // fill the square
squareIsWhite = !squareIsWhite; // flip for next square
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

A different way to draw a checkerboard pattern is to make a 2x2 checkerboard in a drawing program, add that to your project as a resource, pass that image to `+[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:]`, and then you can just fill an area with that color.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the problem is that a row might have an odd number of squares in it, in which case the next row shows the same pattern again.  Here's how I would fix it; I also changed your use of NSBezierPath to NSRectFill() since the latter is both conceptually simpler and likely to be faster.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {    
    for (int j = 0;  j * 20 < self.frame.size.width; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i * 20 < self.frame.size.height; i++) {
            if (((i^j) & 1) == 0)
                [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
            else
                [[NSColor lightGrayColor] set];
            NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(j*20,i*20,20,20));
        }
    }
}
```

The `(i^j) & 1` uses bitwise exclusive-or (the ^ operator) and then bitwise and (the & operator) to combine the odd-even state of both the row and column indices.  There would be various ways to optimize away the multiplies, but this code seems like the clearest way to do it.
A somewhat cleaner version that would run faster and would perhaps avoid some drawing artifacts would involve clearing to one color first and then drawing only squares of the opposite color:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);
    [[NSColor lightGrayColor] set];
    for (int j = 0;  j * 20 < self.frame.size.width; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i * 20 < self.frame.size.height; i++)
            if ((i^j) & 1)
                NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(j*20,i*20,20,20));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt.  If I run the first set of code, I get an entirely gray background.  If I run the second set of code, I get an entirely gray background with white squares diagonally.  And I suppose you have one typo where you have if ((i^j) & 1).

Comment: The first code block had a typo in it that I have just fixed.  (Missing parentheses around (i^j) & 1, needed because of operator precedence issues).  The second code block works perfectly; I just tested it.  I'm not sure why it didn't work for you, but if you thought that its use of ((i^j) & 1) was a typo, and attempted to correct that typo, then perhaps you introduced an error.  In any case, both code blocks work perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your view is not redrawn just because it is resized! So your checkerboard gets squeezed or stretched together with the view. It is up to you to call `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: Pardon me, but there is no guarantee that the frame itself is a square.  So I can't divide the width and the height each by a different number.